# List of @ContentChild() angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have one component that has this template:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-light bg-faded noselect">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

If i need get the childs inside `<ng-content>` i use @ContentChild(), but i need get a list of components that are inside a `<ng-content>`. How do this ?

Comment: There is also `@ContentChildren()`

Comment: Is it child or children? What are their types?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When i used `@ContentChild()` with one component was ok, but for get a list of components i needed use @ContentChildren(Component) components: QueryList<Component>, this resolved my problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer One more question... It's possible to remove one item of a QueryList<Component> ? If i make this, the item will be removed from the dom ?

Comment: No, you can't modify `QueryList`. If you create the elements using `*ngFor`, then you can remove the item from the array you pass to `*ngFor` to get the element removed.

Comment: I know this, but im not use `*ngFor`, im using `<ng-content>` and need remove elements.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I dont know if this is sure, but im using `@ContentChildren (Component, {read: ElementRef}) components: QueryList <ElementRef>`, and so is possible to use `remove ()` method from `nativeElement`.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html doesn't have a remove. if you use `this.components.toArray().remove()` then this doesn't change the `QueryList` but only the array returned by `toArray()` and this won't have any effect on the DOM or the `QueryList` itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128940/discussion-between-carlinhos-and-gunter-zochbauer).